# Is there a way for AppleScript to detect when a Desktop is switched?

Tags: applescript, desktop, spaces

When I switch desktops, I want to have a way to remind me of the purpose of that desktop.  I'm thinking of using AppleScript to detect when I switch desktops, and show a pop up of sorts.

Desktops / popups would contain a label of some sort ("work", "communication", etc).  I'm thinking of launching a browser window, bring it to front, and update the contents to say the purpose.

In my head this sounds doable, I just need to find the event, if any that is related to Spaces/MissionControl.

Comment: I won't post an "Answer" here. Just a "working answer": . . . You can use an indirect GUI "variable" to tell you where you are: . . . set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"/"} . . _/¯. . tell application "System Events" to set BGpict to last text item of item 1 of (picture of every desktop as list) . . .  which e.g. returns "Lion.jpg" on one of my 4 workspaces, "Sierra.jpg" on another, which means I was using desktop 3 first and desktop 1 right now. . . . (I assume you'll find ways to apply this "bit", considering your reputation …)

Answer (score -1):

http://piyocast.com/as/archives/5502
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kZbMs1LJt8&feature=youtu.be

You can detect the switch of desktop. Though, Full-screen mode is detected as desktop switching.

Enjoy!